# Error when obtaining child nodes of an ordered list

Tags: javascript, html-lists

I am trying to get children of an `ul`. I am trying to achieve this by `childNodes`. Then I iterate on the nodes to add values to child `list items` of the `unordered list`. But it is not working.

```js
function getListItem() {
  var list = document.getElementById("list").childNodes;

  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    text = document.createTextNode(i);
    list[i].appendChild(text);
  }

}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul id="list">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  <button onclick="getListItem()">Submit</button>
</body>
```

I can't figure out the error coming. Please help me out.

**EDIT 1**

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': This node type does not support this method
```

Comment: Check the first element in [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes). It won't be the first `<li>` element ;)

Comment: You should try to include the error message that you're seeing in the post.

Comment: use .children , .childNode may also return whitespaces

Comment: @MattWatson The error is shown when snippet is running. I felt redundant to write it. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `.childNodes` it may return whitespaces and newline feeds. When you print the element `list` you will be getting following output:

```
[text, li, text, li, text, li, text, li, text, li, text]
```

You see that the first element is a `text` not a `li`. A workaround can be using `getElementsByTagName('li')`.

```js
function getListItem() {

  var list = document.getElementById("list").getElementsByTagName('li');
  console.log(list);
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    text = document.createTextNode(i);
    list[i].appendChild(text);
  }

}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul id="list">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  <button onclick="getListItem()">Submit</button>
</body>
```

Hope this works.

Comment: Thanks it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Use `innerHTML` in this case instead of appending a child. Also, child nodes must be used after the initial declaration of list. Use `children` instead of `childNodes` to get each element in row.

```js
function getListItem() {
  var list = document.getElementById("list");
  var children = list.children
  for (child in children) {
    children[child].innerHTML = child;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul id="list">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  <button onclick="getListItem()">Submit</button>
</body>
```

Comment: @lanS5 I want answer as 0,1,2,3,4

Comment: Sorry,  fixed it up, same thing, just use `children` instead of `childNodes`